# Embedding into a shell script an awk program with a single quote in it

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a one line text file `nik.txt` and a simple awk script as follows:

```
LagartijaNick>cat nik.txt
hey the're
LagartijaNick>cat tmp.awk
BEGIN {}
{
    searchName=tolower($0);
    if ( searchName ~ /'re/ ) {
       print $0
    }
}
LagartijaNick>awk -f tmp.awk nik.txt
hey the're
```

This above awk script prints the entire record as expected.  But now I have to embed the awk into a BASH script, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
infile=$1
function doThis () {
   awk 'BEGIN {}
   {
      searchName=tolower($0);
      if ( searchName ~ /'re/ ) {
         print $0
      }
   }' $infile
}
doThis
exit 0
```

This returns:

```
./tmp.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
./tmp.sh: line 9: `   if ( searchName ~ /\'re/ ) {'
```

Simple, need to escape the single speech mark?  But I can't get it to work.
I've tried:

```
if ( searchName ~ /\'re/ ) {
if ( searchName ~ /''re/ ) {
```

What am I doing wrong?  All I get are syntax error ...

I'm on the following version of bash:

```
LagartijaNick>/bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: You've got a single quote in the middle of your script which ends the quoted command and bash tries interpreretting the `)`. Also the BEGIN block,although not harmful, is entirely pointless. Its' really difficult to escape single quotes in bash, you'd be better off passing it as a variable to the script `-vQ="'"` and then your regex comparison would be `$0 ~ Q"re"`

Comment: `grep -i "'re" nik.txt`

Comment: The script is confusingly formatted. Are the backticks (\`) actually part of your script or was that an attempt to mark the whole thing as code? I started to edit your question to fix the formatting and noticed that you don't have a set of curly braces defining the extent of the function `doThis` so it's difficult to know exactly what you intended. (Maybe that's the problem?)

Comment: I should say *part of the problem*. Obviously you do need to escape the single quote too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorporating the suggestion of setting a variable with the single quote and removing the unnecessary BEGIN:

```
#!/bin/bash
infile=$1
function doThis () {
    read -d '' cmd <<EOA
    awk -vQ="'" '
    {
        searchName=tolower(\$0);
        if ( searchName ~ Q"re" ) {
            print \$0
        }
    }' $infile
EOA
    eval $cmd
}
doThis
exit 0
```